# SQL Server 2008 update table with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-update

Below you can see my simplified DB model:

[image]

Due to an error there are only null-values in the column **Job.location** where the entries belong to a certain **Plan**. Therefore I want to update all Jobs associated with this Plan, setting **Job.location** to **Location.name** of the **User**, who owns this Plan.

I tried this SQL query:

```
    update dbo.Job set location =

        (select name from dbo.Location as loc where

           loc.objectid = objectid  and loc.user_id in 

           (select userid from dbo.[Plan] as p where p.planid = 20))

        where planid = 20
```

However, the result is always: *0 rows affected*. The subqueries itself work correctly.

How can I achieve that all Jobs with a certain planid are affected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mistake may be that you have no alias for `objectid` column in subquery `loc.objectid = objectid`, so when you running subquery by itself, it just works like `loc.objectid = loc.objectid` and when you running it in the update, it works like `loc.objectid = dbo.Job.objectid`

In your schema it's possible to have multiple locations for users, but supposing you have only one location per user and object, you can try this query:

```
update dbo.Job set
    location = L.Name
from dbo.Job as J
    inner join dbo.[Plan] as P on P.planid = J.planid
    inner join dbo.Location as L on L.user_id = P.userid and L.objectid = J.objectid
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Just had to add 'where J.planid = 20' in the last row.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
j
SET Job.location = loc.name
FROM
Job j
INNER JOIN Plan p ON j.planid = p.planid
INNER JOIN aspnet_Users u ON p.userid = u.UserId
INNER JOIN Location loc ON u.UserId = loc.user_id
WHERE j.planid = 20 
AND p.planid = 20
```